# missing value when calculating running medians?

Tags: r, missing-data

I would like to smooth out a time series to avoid spurious jitter/error. In other words I want to do some very local robust smoothing.

I came across rollmean and rollmedian in the zoo package but ran into a problem because my vector had a NA in it. I then read somewhere that those zoo functions use runmed and therein lies the problem.

==examples==

```
median(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,7,NA,1,2,3,10,10,10),na.rm = TRUE)
runmed(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,7,NA,1,2,3,10,10,10),k=3)
```

The first line returns 2, but would have returned NA if `na.rm = TRUE` was not included. The second line returns `Error in runmed(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 7, NA, 1, 2, 3, 10, 10, 10), k = 3) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)`. There is no way to add a na.rm argument to the line.

**How can I get runmed to handle the NA?** By the way, rollmean returns a vector which is correct up to the NA and then returns NA for every value thereafter.

Comment: `rollmean` and `rollmean` in zoo are intended for speed and therefore have certain limitations so that they run faster -- as discussed in their help file.  If your situation does not fit within those limitations you can still use `rollapply` in which case you can provide whatever function you want, e.g.  `rollapply(x, k, function(x) median(x, na.rm = TRUE))` .  Note that the help file says: " The default method of ‘rollmean’ does not handle inputs that contain ‘NA’s. In such cases, use ‘rollapply’ instead."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `na.omit`

```
runmed(na.omit(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,7,NA,1,2,3,10,10,10)),k=3)
# [1]  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  3 10 10 10
#attr(,"k")
#[1] 3
```

Or use one of the `na.*` functions from **zoo** (`na.locf`, `na.approx`, `na.spline`, `na.aggregate`, etc)
e.g.

```
runmed(na.locf(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,7,NA,1,2,3,10,10,10)),k=3)
#[1]  1  1  1  2  2  2  7  7  2  2  3 10 10 10
#attr(,"k")
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks @GSee. I was reading the zoo help. I just discovered the plethora of functions to guess the NA in a time series. `na.omit` is unsatisfactory because it drops the NA which gives a vector of shorter length than the original which will mess up plotting against timestamps or other variables.

Answer (score 1):

See `runquantile` from the [caTools package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caTools/index.html).